# Slow MEAN Stack Web applications

Tags: performance, optimization, cpanel, mean-stack, shared-hosting

I have three MEAN Stack built web applications hosted on a shared hosting plan. It's running really slow (takes minutes to login and minutes to call the database) and I'm not sure how to optimise the performance. I have created three backend servers so that each application can can call the backend separately. I have ensured that my files are gzipped and are on HTTP3. What else should/can I do on top on that? I can't seem to find much related information online. Please give me any suggestions that you may have!

Would implementing lazy loading help? If so, please share some easy examples because I'm still new. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest moving off of shared hosting and using one of the newer generation developer-focused hosting platforms like [Render](https://render.com) or [Adaptable.io](https://adaptable.io). Adaptable includes MongoDB, so it's great for MEAN stack. With Render, you'd probably use [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/atlas). Both provide free tiers that smaller apps can fit within.

With any of the next-gen hosting platforms, you just connect a GitHub repo with your source code and they automatically deploy your app to the cloud. You don't have to deal with keeping servers up to date, optimizing database performance or anything like that.

Comment: Thanks Mark! I've started using Cloudflare and now it is faster. Will look at these options if the app is starting to slow down again. Thanks again